# Do SAP ME table relationship diagrams exist?

Tags: sql-server, sap-erp

I'm trying to make heads or tails of the schema of the SAP Manufacturing Execution tables.  I cannot seem to find a relationship diagram between all the tables.  Does anyone know if one exists, or how to generate my own?

Comment: you can create diagrams in SOL-server, There is an option under your DB name of "DataBase Diagram" right click on it and create new diagram

Answer (score 0):

Generating a diagram of **all** tables might be a problem - I'm not sure whether you'd be able to see anything in a diagram like that. However, if you start from a single table and display it in the ABAP Dictionary (transaction `SE11`), you could try to fiddle around with the pushbutton *Graphic* (Ctrl+Shift+F11) and see where that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a document called "SAP Manufacturing Execution 5.1.3
Object Models Guide" in Service market place which represents relation between commanly used BO. Available in installation guides for 5.1.3. (No major changes so can be used for 5.2 and 6.0 as well.)

I know it is not database table relationship diagram but feels it can help.